# Songs Package lyrics printed in two columns, title and song information across the two columns

Tags: songs

I would like to have a Song with the lyrics printed in two columns but the title and song information across the two columns (Song #1).  The command \pagepreludes is supposed to do that.  However, it renders a weird layout.
This is the output I want (test code after the image does not render what I want)
I need help on getting 1) Top Align Second verse on right column (Song #1) with Verse 1 on the left column and 2) Put all three songs in one page

**Desired Output**:

[image: Desired Output]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, openany, final, twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[lyric]{songs}


\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
    vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
    mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
    Donec vehicula augue eu neque\par 
    \vspace{24pt}
    \begin{songs}{}
        \songcolumns{2}
        
        %% page preludes yields weird page layout
        {\pagepreludes{
            \beginsong{Song 1}[by={Beagles}, li={licensed by no one}]
            \beginverse*
            On a dark desert highway
            Cool wind in my hair
            Warm smell of colitas
            \endverse 
            
            \beginverse*
            Rising up through the air
            Up ahead in the distance
            I saw a shimmering light
            My head grew heavy and my sight grew dim
            I had to stop for the night
            \endverse 
            
            % no effect, unless is under multicol enviroment  
            %\nextcol
            
            \beginverse*
            There she stood in the doorway
            I heard the mission bell
            And I was thinking to myself
            "This could be Heaven or this could be Hell"
            Then she lit up a candle
            And she showed me the way \ldots
            \endverse 
            
            \endsong
        %this is the end of \pagepreludes - includes only song#1
        }}%
        
        \beginsong{Song 2}[by={Money M}, li={licensed by no two}]
        \beginverse*
        By the rivers of babylon, there we sat down
        Ye-eah we wept, when we remembered zion.
        \endverse 
        \beginverse*
        By the rivers of babylon, there we sat down
        Ye-eah we wept, when we remembered zion.
        \endverse 
        \beginverse*
        When the wicked
        Carried us away in captivity
        Required from us a song
        Now how shall we sing the lord's song in a strange land
        \endverse 
        
        \endsong
        
        \beginsong{Song 3}[by={Beagles}]
        \beginverse*
        On a dark desert highway
        Cool wind in my hair
        Warm smell of colitas
        Rising up through the air
        Up ahead in the distance
        I saw a shimmering light
        My head grew heavy and my sight grew dim
        I had to stop for the night
        \endverse 
        
        \beginverse*
        There she stood in the doorway
        I heard the mission bell
        And I was thinking to myself
        "This could be Heaven or this could be Hell"
        Then she lit up a candle
        And she showed me the way \ldots
        \endverse 
        
        \endsong
        
    \end{songs}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because package `songs` seems to have a lot of interaction with layout (page-builder), I suggest switching to (the newer) package `leadsheet`. It seems to be more compliant with "regular Latex-tricks wrt layout". Main changes:

- `usepackage[full]{leadsheets}` % see manual for options
- `usepackage{multicol}` % as you want to have the first song split like a newspaper
- for simplicity I just copied the first song 2 times
- please consult the manual for setting titles etc.
- put Song 1 into a first multicol{2}
- put a `\hrule` just to please MY eyes
- put Song 2 + 3  into a second multicol{2}

**P.S.:** This package is intended to create books. See ch. 7 in the manual.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, openany, final, twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[full]{leadsheets} % <<< replace
\usepackage{multicol} % <<< for layout


\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.  Donec vehicula augue eu neque
%    \vspace{24pt}
    
\begin{multicols}{2}% NEW
    \begin{song}{title={Song 1}}% <<< please consult the manual
%            \beginsong{Song 1}[by={Beagles}, li={licensed by no one}]
            \begin{verse}
            On a dark desert highway
            Cool wind in my hair
            Warm smell of colitas
            \end{verse}
            
            \begin{verse}
            Rising up through the air
            Up ahead in the distance
            I saw a shimmering light
            My head grew heavy and my sight grew dim
            I had to stop for the night
            \end{verse}
            
            % no effect, unless is under multicol enviroment  
            %\nextcol
            
            \begin{verse}
            There she stood in the doorway
            I heard the mission bell
            And I was thinking to myself
            "This could be Heaven or this could be Hell"
            Then she lit up a candle
            And she showed me the way \ldots
            \end{verse}           
    \end{song}
\end{multicols}
\hrule% <<< just to please MY eyes

\begin{multicols}{2}% <<< next layout section
     \begin{song}{title={Song 2}}% <<< for simplicity, just copied
%            \beginsong{Song 1}[by={Beagles}, li={licensed by no one}]
            \begin{verse}
            On a dark desert highway
            Cool wind in my hair
            Warm smell of colitas
            \end{verse}
            
            \begin{verse}
            Rising up through the air
            Up ahead in the distance
            I saw a shimmering light
            My head grew heavy and my sight grew dim
            I had to stop for the night
            \end{verse}
            
            % no effect, unless is under multicol enviroment  
            %\nextcol
            
            \begin{verse}
            There she stood in the doorway
            I heard the mission bell
            And I was thinking to myself
            "This could be Heaven or this could be Hell"
            Then she lit up a candle
            And she showed me the way \ldots
            \end{verse}           
    \end{song}


    \begin{song}{title={Song 3}}
%            \beginsong{Song 1}[by={Beagles}, li={licensed by no one}]
            \begin{verse}
            On a dark desert highway
            Cool wind in my hair
            Warm smell of colitas
            \end{verse}
            
            \begin{verse}
            Rising up through the air
            Up ahead in the distance
            I saw a shimmering light
            My head grew heavy and my sight grew dim
            I had to stop for the night
            \end{verse}
            
            % no effect, unless is under multicol enviroment  
            %\nextcol
            
            \begin{verse}
            There she stood in the doorway
            I heard the mission bell
            And I was thinking to myself
            "This could be Heaven or this could be Hell"
            Then she lit up a candle
            And she showed me the way \ldots
            \end{verse}           
    \end{song}
\end{multicols}% <<<
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I must use the Songs package to take advantage of printing the chords associated with the Lyrics for the musicians and other tools like printing guitar tabs, transposing the musical piece, etc..  I print only the lyrics for the singers.  Thank you, but switching to leadsheets is not an option